# Unknown VueKonva Type w/ TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, konva, vue-konva

I recently configured TypeScript for my Vue 2 project. Everything is working except for my VueKonva plugin - I receive the error below on app launch.

I tried adding `"vue-konva",` to `types` in `tsconfig.json` but no luck. Creating a `vue-konva.d.js` file also didn't help. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
Failed to compile.

src/main.ts:8:3
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(options?: ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 6 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ VueKonva: PluginObject<{}> | PluginFunction<{}>; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 6 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'VueKonva' does not exist in type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 6 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(options?: ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 6 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ VueKonva: PluginObject<{}> | PluginFunction<{}>; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 6 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'VueKonva' does not exist in type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 6 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(options?: ComponentOptions<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 7 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ VueKonva: PluginObject<{}> | PluginFunction<{}>; render: (h: CreateElement) => VNode; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 7 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'VueKonva' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>, ... 7 more ..., ComponentOptionsMixin>'.
     6 |
     7 | new Vue({
  >  8 |   VueKonva,
       |   ^^^^^^^^
     9 |   render: h => h(App)
    10 | }).$mount("#app");
    11 |
```

main.ts

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "@/App.vue";
import VueKonva from 'vue-konva';

Vue.use(VueKonva);

new Vue({
  VueKonva,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "vue-konva",
      "vuetify",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why did you put VueKonva in you're Vue instance ? You already did a Vue.use(VueKonva);

Comment: Thanks! I've confirmed that Vue.use() is the proper approach for the VueKonva plugin and removing it from the Vue instance resolved the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message points correctly at your problem.

```
  >  8 |   VueKonva,
       |   ^^^^^^^^
```

Check the [project](https://github.com/konvajs/vue-konva) documentation on how to use VueKonva.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueKonva from 'vue-konva';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueKonva);
app.mount('#app');
```

Here is the working example for **Vue v3**

```js
const { createApp } = Vue 

const app = createApp({
data() {
  return {
    configKonva: {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
    },
    configCircle: {
      x: 100,
      y: 100,
      radius: 70,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 4,
    }
  }
}});
app.use(VueKonva);
app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-stage ref="stage" :config="configKonva">
    <v-layer ref="layer">
      <v-circle :config="configCircle"></v-circle>
    </v-layer>
  </v-stage>
</div>
<!--1. Link Vue Javascript & Konva-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.47/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.4.3/konva.min.js"></script>
<!--2. Link VueKonva Javascript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-konva@3.0.2/umd/vue-konva.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

1. Vue v2 has no `$mount` method.
2. Do not put the plugin inside the App definition

Your code

```
new Vue({
  // this is not necessary -> VueKonva,
  render: h => h(App)
}) // this is not necessary -> .$mount("#app");
```

Here is the working example for **Vue v2**

```js
Vue.use(VueKonva)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      configKonva: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
      },
      configCircle: {
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        radius: 70,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-stage ref="stage" :config="configKonva">
    <v-layer ref="layer">
      <v-circle :config="configCircle"></v-circle>
    </v-layer>
  </v-stage>
</div>
<!--1. Link Vue Javascript & Konva-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.4.3/konva.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<!--2. Link VueKonva Javascript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-konva@2.1.7/umd/vue-konva.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @tolbxela, thank you for your time. Your solution is specific to Vue 3 - my project is using Vue 2 so this didn't resolve the error. I double checked my original post and it matches the recommended syntax in vue-konva project. I'm still getting the same error. Can you take another look?

Comment: Check the update for Vue v2